# using android emulators with wdmycloud

Tags: android, android-emulator

I develope my projects on a WD MyCloud so I can access the projects from my different dev devices(desktop,laptop,tablet) but the android emulators won't do this.The build fails, the windows phone emulators don't have this issue. If I use a local harddrive usb drive etc.. the build has no problems. The emulators have no problem with my firewall and I can surf the net with the emulators so I know they are network capable!
Any ideas on why this is not working? Thank-You in advance for any help!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the build fails"? Can you add some log output or error messages what exactly is failing?

Comment: Here is the output from a blank hello World app:

Comment: >The "BuildApk" task failed unexpectedly.
2>System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file '\\WDMYCLOUD\Public\Shared Android Dev\VS 2015\HelloWorld_Android\HelloWorld_Android\obj\Debug\android\bin\HelloWorld_Android.HelloWorld_Android.apknew' because it is being used by another process.